# Migration Server A to Server B (SharePoint)

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I am struggling since a few days with this SharePoint issue and I will be really thankful for any help. 
I want to migrate documents, lists and calendars from a SharePoint server A to another sharepoint server B. The migration works great with the documents Files but doesn't work for lists and calenders.
How can I migrate lists and calenders to another server?

PS: I use the  Microsoft SharePoint 2010 .

Thanks and Best Regards,

Elom

Comment: What are  you using for migration. Can you use Backup and Restore procedure for the site? Or you need to just move the specific lists. If the latter then what you can do (if the lists are not too big) you can save them as template with inclusion of content (that is done from the list settings) you can upload then those templates to the new site (In farm B) and re-create the lists.

Comment: You can do backup/restore to the new server, saving as a template and creating on the new server with this template(this would require the servers to be equal, same config etc) or using a thirdparty tool like sharegate. metalogix etc